# SvelteKit: SVG on HTML page, or as standalone SVG file depending on route

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have a component, `image.svelte` which renders an SVG file. On one route, say `/image`, I want a page that includes that component rendered within an HTML document. But if you go to `/image.svg`, I want just the SVG document by itself and I want the page to be served with `Content-Type: image/svg+xml`.

I started by making creating a file like `src/routes/image[ext]/+page.svelte`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to break out of `src/app.html`.

Next I tried making two files, `src/routes/image/+page.svelte` and `src/routes/image.svg/+server.js`, but it doesn't seem to be possible to render components directly from a server-side script in SvelteKit.

So I'm at a loss and haven't find what I'm looking for in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I was pretty close to the answer. I just needed to explore the `svelte` module a little.

I accomplished what I wanted to do by creating one file, `src/routes/image/+page.svelte`, for serving the HTML page with the SVG in it; and by creating a second file, `src/routes/image.svg/+server.js`

I pieced together from error messages and old documentation that importing `svelte/register` no longer worked and I needed to import `svelte/ssr` instead, and that svelte components have a `.render()` method which returns an object with `html`, `css`, and `head` properties. In my case I only needed the `html` property.

This was the final result

```js
import "svelte/ssr"
import Image from "$lib/Image/index.svelte"

export function GET() {
    const {html} = Image.render({svg: true})

    return new Response(html, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "image/svg+xml",
            "Content-Disposition": "inline;filename=image.svg"
        }
    })
}
```